# GCM Curl connection Error

Tags: php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a message from a server to client (android) using GCM and curl,
the code i used worked perfectly for localhost (emulator and device) , however it would not work for a regular server, attached is the code used and the error message,

are there any additional steps or changes i need to do to make the code work for online server. Any help is appreciated :)

```
<?php

function Reg($USER_REG_ID)
{
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $response = array();
    $API_Key = 'AIzaSyCQgPGhpAzuWGuUd0DCI8pYaXXAItthEsg';
    $url     = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where type = 'bus'") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $Registration_ID = $row["user_RegID"];
        array_push($response, $Registration_ID);

    }

//THIS PART SENDS TEH REQUEST USING GCM
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $response,
        'data' => array(
            "message" => $USER_REG_ID
        )
    );

        print_r ($fields);

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $API_Key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch      = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);


}
Reg(1)
?>
```

the fields array

```
Array ( [registration_ids] => Array ( [0] => APA91bFolV5ZK2diIbTyxwPLp6BqTMdhqaMDYgEsGOlznmxn4NRV6QQzPtfr58ORrpmxq0N_UMwz6s30gWgj--w5SqHxCEHh662PnvjDpGce_4EiHDe-muflVYMOsLlbVDRybvNDubX9aF_RE4VPJdArUsqQjcrQRg ) [data] => Array ( [message] => 1 ) )
```

The error message

```
Curl failed: Failed to connect to 2a00:1450:400c:c05::5f: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

If the above doesn't work, you can try to disable ipv6 system wide:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

Comment: @user2652614 i am facing the issue. which solution worked for you. first one is not helping and i dont know where to use the second one

Comment: It was a long time ago, however, i believe I also removed the 's' from https. which made it work. give it a try :)